# Activity lifecyle overlap

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities A, B, C. All A displays is a spinner while getting data from the network. Depending on the data, the next activity may be B or C. Both B and C have a back button which calls super.onBackPressed() to go back to A. At that point, network caching may cause A to *immediately* go back to B or C.

Both B and C use a singleton class with create and destroy methods. I call the singleton's create method in B/C's onCreate and call the singleton's destroy method in B/C's onDestroy.

The problem is overlap: If activity B(1) is running and the user hits the back button, he'll go back to A which may immediately start new activity B(2). However, the B(1) onDestroy method may be called *after* the B(2) onCreate method, which means the singleton's destroy method is called last, causing an exception in B(2):

```
B2 - onCreate (singleton's create method called)
B1 - onDestroy (singleton's destroy method called)
B2 - crashes when trying to use singleton
```

Is there a way to ensure B1 is destroyed before B2 is created? I could put a small minimum delay in A, but that's no guarantee. I've also read that I could make B's launch mode "singleTop" to prevent it from being destroyed in the first place, but I'm not sure if that's appropriate here since the are a series of other activities after B.

Comment: My first thought is to have the singleton do something almost like reference counting; have the create method increment some counter and the destroy method decrement it (and then only _actually_ destroy the singleton if the counter is 0).

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your design, why you have such requirement?

Comment: Why do you have a whole activity just to show a "busy" spinner animation? This should be part of each activity which does network communication.

Comment: Thanks all. Unfortunately, the singleton is Universal imageLoader and I'd rather not change that code if I don't have to. Also, how should I determine whether the first activity is B or C without using activity A to get the answer from the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using singleton in this case is not a good practice and you may want to instantiate the singleton in your application class only once for Application lifecycle.
If you really need a singleton that follows the activity lifecycle then you could have a map of instances binded to the activity's context with lazy inizialization.

```
public class SingleTon {
    static HashMap<Context, SingleTon> instances;

    static SingleTon getInstance(Context c) {
        if (instances.get(c) == null) {
            SingleTon newInstance = new SingleTon();
            instances.put(c, newInstance);
        }
        return instances.get(c);
    }

    static void destroy(Context c) {
        instances.remove(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'd rather not change the Universal imageLoader class to do this. The more I think about it, I think I just shouldn't call the destroy method and not worry about it. It's a singleton after all. I was just trying to avoid its warning: “Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before”